# Numpy is not working after set up new virtual environment (in both base and new env)

Tags: pandas, numpy, virtual-environment

why setting up a virtual environment is giving so many issue? Firstly pandas not working but it is in pip list.
I uninstall pandas and reinstall, it doesn't work. I then uninstall anaconda and reinstall again then it work.
Now numpy is not working in base environment and new environment. I uninstall and reinstalled. It doesn't work.

Am I doing anything wrong during the setting up new env? or it is python bug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are activating the virtual environment prior to installing packages for that specific project & deactivating environment when finished working on that project.